# Rails app turned into HTML on GitHub as I forgot to gitignore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, code-coverage, gitignore

I added SimpleCov and forgot to .gitignore 'coverage' and now my Rails app has accidentally turned into a HTML app on GitHub. This is where my app lives: https://github.com/GeekG1rl/lemon

I tried to add 'coverage' to my .gitignore afterwards and push again but it hasn't updated in my repo (probably because the file is still there).

My assumption is that the directory has already been built but if I delete it, then push again (with 'coverage' in .gitignore), then it will build locally only when being run? If that breaks more things though, I won’t know how to undo that so I'm asking for help before completely breaking it.

I've been coding for three months so please don't be mean if this turns out to be a stupid question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git rm -rf coverage
git commit -m "Remove coverage folder"
git push origin master
```

`.gitignore` only covers newly added files and directories, you must manually remove any existing files or directories when you add them to `.gitignore`.